# How to run a .pyc (compiled python) file?

Tags: python, compiling

When I compile a python file, I get a *.pyc file. When I try to run that, I get a message saying there is no program for running them. When I search for a program online via that option, it says there are none. Can anyone help me run there files?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since your python file is byte compiled you need to run it through the python interpreter

```
python yourfile.pyc
```

The reason you can run your .py files directly is because you have the line

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or something similar on the first line in the .py files.
This tells your shell to execute the file with the Python interpreter.

Comment: To complement this answer: a .pyc file is not *compiled* in the strictest sense of the term, as it is not native machine code. It is, as @tomdachi wrote, python-specific byte-code (very similar to a Java .class), that's why it still needs the python interpreter to execture.

Comment: in fact, the pyc only  was generated when you import the py file. so it is useless to run the pyc file!

Answer (score 3):

To decompile compiled .pyc python3 files, I used `uncompyle6` in my current Ubuntu OS as follows:

1. Installation of uncompyle6:

   ```
   pip3 install uncompyle6
   ```
2. To create a .py file from .pyc file Run:

   ```
   uncompyle6 -o . your_filename.pyc
   ```
3. Automatically a new .py file will be created with the same existing .pyc file name.

Answer (score 1):

Python compiles the .py files and saves it as .pyc files so it can reference them in subsequent invocations. The .pyc contain the compiled bytecode of Python source files, which is what the Python interpreter compiles the source to. This code is then executed by Python's virtual machine. There's no harm in deleting them (.pyc), but they will save compilation time if you're doing lots of processing.

Python is an interpreted language, as opposed to a compiled one, though the distinction can be blurry because of the presence of the bytecode compiler. Compiling usually means converting to machine code which is what runs the fastest. But interpreters take human-readable text and execute it. They may do this with an intermediate stage.

For example, When you run myprog.py source file, the python interpreter first looks to see if any `myprog.pyc` exists (which is the byte-code compiled version of `myprog.py`), and if it is as recent or more recent than `myprog.py`. If so, the interpreter runs it. If it does not exist, or `myprog.py` is more recent than it (meaning you have changed the source file), the interpreter first compiles `myprog.py` to `myprog.pyc`.

There is one exception to the above example. If you put `#! /usr/bin/env python` on the first line of `myprog.py`, make it executable, and then run `myprog.py` by itself.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! This is a nice explanation of why `pyc` files exist but you haven’t answered the question how to run them. It can be qualified as a very extended comment, not an _answer_. Please [edit] your post to add an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the location of the file to $PATH.
To know the directories in your $PATH,
use this command in the terminal
`echo $PATH`
Use this command below to add the location of the file.pyc to $PATH
`export PATH=location of the file.pyc=$PATH`